# MAMP MySQL Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I've run into a issue in my MAMP instillation, I didn't change anything it just happened. I start MAMP perfectly fine and it gives the green light that the MySQL server is up and I can connect to it from the terminal using the mysql command. However when I try and open phpMyAdmin I get this error:

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I didn't change the default username and password and have subsequently tried to reset them to root and root which is what phpMyAdmin thinks they are. However I still get this error. The host is still set to localhost. I've tried uninstalling and reinstall MAMP to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a lot of people where having this error recently.

MAMP had changed the PHP toggle in the preferences pane to 7.0.8, just had to switch it back to 5.6.10.

Comment: I have this EXACT problem. Could you elaborate on what you did here? Thanks!

Comment: If you launch MAMP and click preferences on the PHP tab you should be able to toggle the PHP version being used. PHP 7 is still in beta and not everything supports it which is why these issues are occurring. Change the toggle back to version 5 and everything should start to work again.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I checked MAMP, it was still on 5.6.10.

Comment: @ToeurTenh I have no idea what happened here. But am still using MAMP and it's working. You having issues?

Answer (score 5):

Change these two lines in `config.inc.php` file.

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']  = '127.0.0.1';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']  = '8889';`

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the mysql password for mamp.

I found that tech-otaku explains it well.---https://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/

What he basically says in the link: Stop the servers. Then using the terminal:use the skip-grant-tables command, then --skip-networking command, and flush privileges command. He goes into more detail for the steps on his website.

P.S- You can also stop the mysqld server from the activity monitor. Applications/utilities/activitymoniter (search:mysql)

Answer (score 0):

**Find default mysql host, root and password using mamp on mac**

I got this error too. I followed the path below to find out the default root, host and password information.

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/index.php

*my $source = 'DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost;

my $user = 'root';

my $password = 'root';*

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "MyDatabaseName");
```