# Changed WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) when developing site from localhost. Now, error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress, mamp

Changed WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) when developing site from localhost.

[image]

Now, error establishing a database connection when I go to http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/ and am being denied access to http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/.

[image]

And when I try to Start Servers in MAMP I get this error:

Apache couldn't be started because port 8888 is in use by some other software.

[image]

It was a stupid mistake I know, is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You can't get into phpmyadmin?

Comment: @JakeParis No. I'm getting this error: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory. I'll update the original post with a screenshot.

Comment: You have *2* different issues here, that are unrelated. Changing the WordPress url doesn't affect your access to phpmyadmin.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352629/mamp-mysql-cannot-connect-invalid-settings

Comment: Weird. As soon as I changed the URL in the WordPress dashboard, these problems started happening. I tried updating the PHP version to the older version but I am still unable to start the server/access myphpadmin. I added another screen shot to show the alert message I get when trying to start servers.

Comment: A computer restart would probably fix this. Alternatively, you could open up your activity monitor in Mac, find the **httpd** process and kill them all. (That is Apache). Then try to start MAMP again.

Comment: IT WORKED! And I was able to go into myphpadmin and update the wp_options siteurl and home url. Now everything is running back to normal. Also, I've went ahead and marked your comment as the answer. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to re-access a WordPress site for which you've mistakenly changed the address and home url, open the database via phpmyadmin or some other database editor, look in the `wp_options` table, and modify both **siteurl** and **home** to be the correct url.

Comment: TablePlus is pretty good, as is BeeKeeperStudio https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/ and the latter is free.